# Using MVC Routes as Shortcodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have been trying to implement shortcodes on an ASP.NET MVC web app that allow users to uniquely invoke a given article/page using an assigned short code.

For e.g.: www.mysite.com/power would map to an actual URL: www.mysite.com/Power/Home/.

I have created various routes throughout the site that map these shortcodes to various actions and controllers within the application. From a shortcode/route point of view, everything is working great.

I, however, noticed a couple of interesting things. I have hyperlinks that I use Url.Action method to generate the URL pointing pages. Many of these pages also have short codes associated with them. For e.g.: I have a link that says:

```
 <a href="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Power" })%>"> Go to Power page</a>
```

This is a page that also has the previously mentioned short-code assigned to it. When I use Url.Action, I ideally expect it to create a link as /Power/Home/Index or /Power/Home, but since I also have a route constraint mapped to it, it now generates the link as /power.

Is there a way I can just use the actual link URL when generating links? I only want short-codes when I am sending out emails etc. I want the site to generate actual URLs.

This may or may not be possible, but I wanted to see if there were any ideas out there that I could use.

Anup

Answer (score 0):

Index and Home are likely defined in your route table as defaults for the Action and Controller element.  When you generate the Url it wont include the defaults if they aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own Action overload or helper, which would allow you to take more direct control of the generated URL or action link. You could approach it from two different ways: 1) a helper to generate short-code specific urls and links, and/or 2) a helper to generate the full url and/or link. If Url.Action is returning the short-code version due to your routing configuration, I'd think a good place to start would be the second option, creating a helper/extension method that will generate the full url for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this:

Instead of naming a route with short code to point to the action url, I made the route point to a different Controller action which would then redirect to the actual route that I want it to.

For e.g.: Originally I had the code "power" defined in the route table such that it would point to www.mysite.com/Power/Home.

Now instead of pointing it to that action - Index, controller - Home, area - Power, I make it resolve to: action - Power, Controller - Home, Area - ShortCode.

In the controller now, I simply do a RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Power" });

This ensures that the actual links to /Power/Home do not resolve to the shortcode "power".

This is a simple fix increased the work by a little bit, but works like a charm.